# Java parallel calculation / threading

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, runnable

Here's my problem: I have a population of let's say 200 individuals. The goal is to optimize that population. Each individual has several parameters and these parameters are used to assign a value (quality level) to that individual. The calculation of that value can be done seperately for each individual but takes several seconds each. My laptop has 4 processors and I noticed that the calculations can be done 3 times that fast by using multiple threads (via Runnable, 1 main thread, 7 threads for individuals, 7 individuals are processed simultaneously then the next 7 ones). However, I have no knowledge of threads and my implementation is flawed. Most likely, the program will terminate, but there's also a chance that it will freeze (which may cost me 1 hour of calculations done). The more other programs I run, the higher the chance for failure. So, how to do it properly? Thanks in advance.

```
public class EntropyParralel 
{
    private static final int maxThreads = 7;
    static final int populationSize = 200;
    static Individual[] population;
    static Thread[] threads;
    static int finishedThreads;
    static int startedThreads;

    static class Individual implements Runnable
    {
        // ...

        public void run()
        {
            eval();
            finishedThreads += 1;
        }
    }   

    public static void newEntropy()
    {
        // ...

        threads = new Thread[ population.length ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++ )
            threads[i] = new Thread( population[i] );
        startedThreads = 0; finishedThreads = 0;
        while( finishedThreads < threads.length )
        {
            if ( startedThreads - finishedThreads < maxThreads && startedThreads < threads.length )
            {
                threads[startedThreads].start();
                startedThreads += 1;
            }
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        sortPopulation();

        // ...
    }
}
```

**edit:**

didn't find any decent ExecutorService example regarding simple array calculation. So I continued using Runnable and Thread. This time counting finished and new threads via thread.getState().equals(Thread.State.TERMINATED) in every main loop frame. And it seems to work properly. Had a test run over 10,000 iterations on a smaller problem and it didn't freeze.

```
public class EntropyParallel 
{
    private static final int maxThreads = 7;
    static final int populationSize = 200;

    static class Individual implements Runnable
    {
        // ...

        public void run()
        {
            eval();
        }
    }

    public static void newEntropy()
    {
        // ...

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[ population.length ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++ )
            threads[i] = new Thread( population[i] );
        while( true )
        {
            int finishedThreads = 0; int availableThreads = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++ )
            {
                if ( threads[i].getState().equals(Thread.State.TERMINATED) )
                    finishedThreads += 1;
                else if ( threads[i].getState().equals(Thread.State.NEW) )
                    availableThreads += 1;
            }
            if ( finishedThreads == threads.length )
                break;
            for ( int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++ ) 
            {
                if ( threads.length - finishedThreads - availableThreads >= maxThreads || availableThreads == 0 )
                    break;
                if ( threads[i].getState().equals(Thread.State.NEW) ) 
                {
                    threads[i].start();
                    availableThreads -= 1;
                }
            }
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        sortPopulation();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: See Executors. and ExecutorService

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create and start all threads manually. Look at java.util.concurrent.CompletionService. You can create small pieces of code that will do only the calculation and submit then to this CompletionService, then it will run all your tasks and you can look at it when it is finished.

I suggest you take a look at ExecutorCompletionService and Executors class. They will help you